# Email Template Using Letterhead - Make Images in Letterhead Clickable

Tags: support

How can I make the images in my letterhead email templates click-able and linked to my website?

I know it can be done using custom HTML email templates, but then this prevents me from being able to edit the body of the email prior to sending, which I also need to do.

Answer (score 1):

one option is to host your images externally and include them as image link in the email template. in this case you can't use letterhead.